# How to design a ViewController with complex TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Imagine this scenario:

- I've 10 different and custom UITableViewCell: one with a textfield,
  one with a button, one with some labels, one with a textview, one
  with an imageView and so on.
- I've a ViewController with a tableView where I wanna display these cells.
- The number of cell displayed can vary based on some conditions (and also the height, the background color and other parameters)
- The user can interact with these cells

What is the best way to design this in respect of the MVC and maintain the ViewController lightweight and maintainable as possible?
How to take advantage of Swift language in doing this?
Is there any famous and consolidate design pattern to apply?

Answer (score 1):

i will try to share some of my experience:

Create separate custom **UITableViewCelll** as per requirement like : textfield, textview, imageview, label etc. this class **must not** dependent on data calculation it is only for cosmetics UI. that means there must not be any method like updateCellWithData:(someDATAObj). **This logic must go in some cetegory as discussed below.**

Register separate custom UITableViewCelll with your tableview.

Create separate class (NSObject) as **datasource** and **delegate** for your UITableView.

**Use category to populate data in your custom UITableView Cell.** some thing like updateCellWithData:(someDATAObj).

Use **constant** file for your constants like height for tableView Cell, reuse identifier names, notification name.

try with some code atleast, then we can help you with best.